# How do I perform a right-click-drag with the trackpad on Windows 7 under Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, contextual-menu

I tried two-finger-click and drag. Nope, doesn't work.

I tried clicking in the bottom right corner with one finger, but can't seem to drag.

I'm on a early 2011 Macbook Pro running Bootcamp 4 and OS X Lion.

Comment: What version of bootcamp?

Comment: Im using version 4 of Bootcamp.

Comment: Did you look at the settings in the control pannel for bootcamp? Also, I haven't seen this problem myself but a little Googling turned up people reverting to version 3.1 of the trackpad drivers for bootcamp.

Comment: Yes, I looked into the control panel. It has settings to allow me to enable lower-right-corner emulation of right-clicking, which works... I can definitely right-click, I just can't DRAG while holding down the right button.

Comment: Does it work if you plug in a mouse?

Comment: Sure it works with a mouse; it's the Bootcamp trackpad driver that's giving me the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug in a mouse it works, I don't have a mouse though so I've been hoping to find a solution to using the trackpad, and since Control-click doesn't work, I'm stuck.